# I wanna create a recipe / blog slider (for telephone version of the site) that shows 1 recipe and also half of the next recipe

Tags: css, wordpress, widget, slider, elementor

Im trying to build something like this in my wordpress site using elementor pro. i want the slider to show 1 recipe and also a little bit of the next one so you can see there are multiple recipes and that u need to scroll to the site.
[example of how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OL4sx.png)

I already have a custom loop template. and use the widget post as of right now.

[this is how it looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOkkA.png)

i dont know the css behind this and cant seem to find it anywhere on the internet. hope someone can help me here.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to put the widgets in a row and display scrollbar.

I believe there are a few options how to do it, but basically what you need to add to your css is `overflow: auto` - that means to show a scrollbar when there is not enough space to display all the widgets together.

An example with `overflow: auto` and `display: flex`:

```css
.widgets-container {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}

.widget {
  flex-shrink: 0;
 
  /* visual styling */
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  border: 2px dashed green;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="widgets-container">
  <div class="widget">Widget 1</div>
  <div class="widget">Widget 2</div>
  <div class="widget">Widget 3</div>
</div>
```